# Question based on a blog post I was not aware it was a theorem stated and proved in another site

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deletion

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2248/how-to-prove-the-midpoint-of-a-chord-is-also-the-midpoint-of-the-line-segment-def) of mine was based on an exercise posted in a blog. I asked an identification of the theorem it refers to. This theorem was identified in a comment to my question: it is stated and proved in another site, which I did not know.

Should my question on the main site be closed or deleted? I am not sure, but it may be   better to do so.

In such a case I ask someone with the power for that to close/remove it.

**Edit:** In the 1st paragraph, "here" deleted *[My question about theorem's name, etc. was posted in the main site, not here]* .

In the 2nd paragraph, "safer" changed to "better". *["safer" was related with the concern I had about copyright: see my answer to KennyTM's comment below].*

I hope this improves this question.

The tag "specific-question" has been added previously. A doubt of mine: Should specific questions  be avoided here?

**Update:** quoting from above

> Should my question on the main site be closed or deleted? I am not sure, but it may be better to do so.
>   In such a case I ask someone with the power for that to close/remove it.

**It is now my opinion that this concern of mine was unjustified.**

Comment: How is it related to copyright?

Comment: @KennyTM: Thanks for your comment which made me think again. I removed the copyright tag, because I have changed my mind and now think that the concern I had with the copyright was a silly one.

Comment: By specific-question, I meant that your meta question is about a specific question on the main site. That's perfectly fine, I just prefer to keep track of such things.

Comment: @Kaestur: Oh, now I see. My doubt is cleared thanks to your reply.

Comment: There is a new meta question that is partially related to this one, in my view.

http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/656/require-proper-citation-for-verbatim-quoted-questions-answers-proofs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the OP have resolved the problem, they could answer it themselves.

Of course, for this question I prefer Jorge to answer it. The actual answer doesn't need to be too detailed. Just the name "Butterfly theorem", the key geometrical theorems used there, and the link should be enough. (Something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794503/what-is-this-pattern-called-helps-avoid-type-casting/794507#794507) on SO; see [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/why-is-linking-bad/7519#7519) on meta for detail about links.)

Comment: Note that the SO question linked to asks only for the name, meaning that such a brief answer is complete. Américo's question does ask how to prove a theorem, and I believe a complete answer should address that.

Comment: @Kaestur: But the last sentence of the question is " *What is the theorem this exercise refers to?* Or how does one prove it?". Of course a complete answer is much better.

Comment: @Kaestur: not 'and' either ;)

Comment: @KennyTM: So we agree that name only is correct, name+proof is complete?

Comment: @Kaestur: I agree.

Comment: @KennyTM, @Kaestur: My main interest when I asked this question in the main site was in the proof. I asked the theorem's name because knowing it I would try to search for a proof. I thought that it would also be fine for me if someone gives a proof, without indicating the name by which the theorem is known.