# Require proper citation for verbatim quoted questions, answers, proofs?

Tags: discussion, policy, citation

Recently I had the displeasure of seeing a famous ingenious proof quoted here without any attribution whatsoever. Some readers could have easily been misled to believe that the proof was due to the poster. Also there have been a number of questions *and* answers that were quoted verbatim from problem books without any hint of the source. Should we require proper citations in such cases - esp. when the poster is clearly copying verbatim from another source?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by require? A policy of "we should require citations" is very vague. For people answering this question, please be detailed. [Tom's answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/656/require-proper-citation-for-verbatim-quoted-questions-answers-proofs/658#658) is a good example of one that recommends specific actions.

Comment: My previous thread was about the same issue: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/596/texts-that-are-verbatim-copied-from-somewhere-else

Comment: OK!  So far we had no success in getting any form of discouragement of homework problems copied from textbooks.  Maybe we can sting these guys for plagiarism!

Answer (score 18):

I really think the appropriate citations must be edited *into the main body* of the answers, or they need to be removed from the site entirely.  The same thing goes for the questions.  This is pure, cut-and-dry plagiarism and should not be tolerated.  **To put it as mildly as I can: It reflects poorly on all of us and it is unprofessional.**

Comment: Tom, I would appreciate if you could give your opinion on the case I describe in my answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Americo: I accidentally deleted my comment, what I had said was that I think your question was a good example of [this principle](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-ask-a-good-question/651#651) of shared community knowledge in action.

Comment: Thanks! My concern with closing or deleting my question on the main site seems now to be unjustified. Regarding the answer, copying a small proof is also a non-issue, according to ShreevatsaR's comment below.

Answer (score 15):

Absolutely.  To me it seems incredibly rude to do otherwise.  On MO this is less of an issue because grad students and professors in mathematics are already trained to cite sources constantly, but I think that habit is just as necessary here.

Apart from the social aspect, answers and questions alike are more useful when the relevant sources are cited.

Answer (score 2):

Taking into consideration Quaochu's and Tom's answers, I explain my opinion and one example I would like advice.

1. Proper citations should always be done either in answers or in questions.
2. Plagiarism is intolerable.
3. I agree that in same cases (this is vage but I am not able to define them more precisely) there is a need to remove them from the site.

In my first [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2248/how-to-prove-the-midpoint-of-a-chord-is-also-the-midpoint-of-the-line-segment-def) (the only one I've asked up to now) in the main site I quoted properly, I think, an exercise in a blog post, and indicated a proof of mine that was wrong to show that I had worked on it.

I asked the name of the theorem it referred to or a proof of it. I got a comment with the name of the theorem and a link to the site where several proofs are presented. Then one of the proofs was adapted (the notation was converted) and posted verbatim as an answer, citing the source.

In [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/604/a-question-asked-in-a-blog-post-that-i-was-not-aware-that-it-was-a-theorem-stated) meta-question I wrote: "Should my question on the main site be closed or deleted? I am not sure, but it may be <strike>safer</strike> better to do so."

If anything has to be removed, please comment and/or do it and excuse this long explanation.

Comment: I think the specific question and answer you're referring to is a non-issue. The source has been properly cited, right from the start. So it's not even relevant to this meta question here. There is nothing wrong at all with copying a small proof like that with attribution. It's neither "safer" nor "better" to remove it.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, thanks for your opinion.